# Add to begining and end of various formulas without changing formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a range of cells that I need to have the formula multiply the results of the formulas by .5.

All the cells have similar, but different formulas

Example:

Cell A1 has formula =SUM(COUNTIFS($L:$L,"Both",$K:$K,$N30,$F:$F,"M-*",$I:$I,{"M-*","N-*"}))+COUNTIFS($L:$L,"Both",$F:$F,"M-*",$K:$K,$N30,$H:$H,"No *")
Cell B1 has formula =SUM(COUNTIFS($L:$L,"Both",$K:$K,$N30,$F:$F,"N-*",$I:$I,{"M-*","N-*"}))+COUNTIFS($L:$L,"Both",$F:$F,"N-*",$K:$K,$N30,$H:$H,"No *")
etc... for many cells

Is there a way I can use find and replace to change every formula to

=.5*(SUM(COUNTIFS($L:$L,"Both",$K:$K,$N30,$F:$F,"M-*",$I:$I,{"M-*","N-*"}))+COUNTIFS($L:$L,"Both",$F:$F,"M-*",$K:$K,$N30,$H:$H,"No *")), and so on for every cell, adding the ".5*(" at the begining and the ")" at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what I wanted without resorting to VBA, was to use find and replace to remove the "=" from all the formulas in the range, then use find and replace to add ")" to the end of the formula [which Excel now only saw as a string] and then use find and replace again to add "=.5*(" to the begining.

That was easier than manually adding the needed aspects to the formulas.

Comment: Answer your own question is a good practice,, but what you have to do is,, show a proper solution,,, [Please refer this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)